# How to update the weight when Adaboost is used for regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, adaboost

When Adaboost is used for regression, in the $m$ step, we suppose $G_m(x)$ is $m$-classifier with sample $\{(x_i,y_i)\}$; the error of i-th sample is $e^i_m;$ the weight of $e^i_m$ is $w^i_m;$ the weight of $G_m(x)$ is $\alpha_m$ and the total eroor is $e_m = \sum\limits_iw^i_m e^i_m.$

We suppose the loss function can be following:
$$|y_i - G_m(x_i)|,\ (y_i - G_m(x_i))^2.$$

Then

1. How to define $e^i_m?$ I saw some reference defined as $E_m = \max\limits_i |y_i - G_m(x_i)|$

   1. $|y_i - G_m(x_i)|:$ $e_m^i = \dfrac{|y_i - G_m(x_i)|}{E_m}$
   2. $(y_i - G_m(x_i))^2:$ $e_m^i = \dfrac{(y_i - G_m(x_i))^2}{E_m}$
2. How to calculated $\alpha_m$ as a function of $e_m?$
3. How update $w_{m+1}^i$ based on $w_{m}^i?$

Comment: Can you please point to the paper with this notation?

Comment: @usεr11852 sorry, I only have the Chinese version of the reference, but in summary, my question is how to apply the AdaBoost  to the regression or is it just the GDBT? I saw many related answers here, but no one explicitly show the updating process of the AdaBoost for regression when the loss function is given (say squared loss).